# Signout from all Browsers

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, webapi

The back-end is written in ASP.NET Core Web API and front-end with Angular 15.

There are different menu items that navigate to different pages in my current project.

The same site is opened in different browsers like Firefox, Edge and Google Chrome with different pages

If the user signs out from one page, the request will be sent to web API and from there I am calling `SignOutAsync` of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` Namespace.

When this `SignOutAsync` is called, it is only logging out from the browser where it is called. But not other browsers.

**EDIT**

Below is the code related to JWT that is implemented in Asp.Net Core Middleware.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
.AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
{
    options.Authority = 
    builder.Configuration["IdentityServer:Authority"];
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
```

Could anyone direct me on how to achieve this? This feature is implemented with logging out of Gmail accounts from different browsers or WhatsApp signing out from all devices. I need that similar functionality.

Comment: Sometimes that's quite arbitrary but in topic: do you have push communication from server to browsers?

Comment: I have no much idea on what you are talking..

Comment: What you're asking for isn't really possible (it _can be_ done... depending on various details, but you haven't shared those details with us) because different browsers hold different sessions entirely. If your system is using _stateless_ authentication then you can only rely on session-expiration or cookie-expiration - or use a (cumbersome) session revocation system (which is nontrivial).

Comment: _"This feature is implemented with logging out of Gmail accounts from different browsers or WhatsApp signing out from all devices. I need that similar functionality."_ - that sounds like you're using some form of Federated Identity like OIDC or SAML - in that case **you can't, by design**: Google, etc don't want to give third-party Relying Party sites the ability to forcibly end their users' sessions for what should be very obvious reasons.

Comment: Is it possible to store session details in database and when that session is removed from there, then can I fire an event to Angular and close all the Browsers?

Comment: Could you please provide more on session revocation system?

Comment: We are implementing JWT for tokens in Web API and Angular.

Comment: Question edited with JWT Code.

Comment: Do you understand why it's not possible for JS running in one web-browser to command another web-browser to close?

Comment: As you're using JWTs that means you're using stateless authentication - personally I wouldn't bother with trying to implement token revocation - just use a short JWT lifetime (say, 5 minutes).

Comment: But you mentioned that there are other ways like session revocation system, OIDC or SAML..

Comment: I would not want to implement short JWT lifetime. Looking eagerly to implement Signout method.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @Dai Even cumbersome approach is also ok for me..

Comment: @Dai If I make JWT as Stateful, then is this achievable by killing the token from Server Side?

Comment: @CPK_2011 _"If I make JWT as Stateful"_ - with respect, you've only demonstrated that you don't understand what "stateful" means, because any bearer-token scheme involving structured tokens containing claims _are_ stateles. You can't "make" JWT stateless - then it wouldn't be a JWT, it would be a reference-token.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for pointing out. How can we implement with Reference-token?

Comment: @Dai Could you please provide any sample code that implements Reference-token related to this topic?

Comment: @CPK_2011 It sounds like you should hire a consultant who specialises in this. The scope of your question is too large to be answered for free, by unpaid volunteers, on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Because JWT is stateless, you'll have to check it against the DB. But this will require some changes in the filter chain and it may have impact on the performance because it will run queries every time on the revoked JWT table.
(with time the table can become 'n' records, but this can be fixed so the table can be cleaned every <time_of_token_expiration>)

Comment: Could you please provide any link or the code here so that it would be easy for me to implement?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# (I've done it in Spring Boot), but you can check the class where you check if the token is valid and before that line of code, add the check against the DB. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Could you tell me what and all I have to make this success in some steps..? Spring Boot code is also ok for me.. I will try to translate it..

Comment: Also would like to know how it keeps track of the opened Browsers and how are we going to kill that Browsers.

Comment: @CPK_2011 You can't "kill" browsers like that. It's impossible. I just don't understand how you're even working on this project without first having an understanding of how the web even works...

Comment: @Dai I mean killing the Session Token.

Comment: Dai it is actually possible. On the next API call it will throw 401 error and if there is good error handling on the FE it will redirect it to for example login page.

Btw @CPK_2011 here is the code you can modify

https://medium.com/code-with-farhan/spring-security-jwt-authentication-authorization-a2c6860be3cf#:~:text=public%20Claims%20resolveClaims,ex%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D

Comment: @ПредрагДишленковиќ You have mentioned how JWT is implemented with Spring Boot. I am looking on how to kill the JWT token for all the Browsers.

Comment: yes, as I said... in the function where you check the JWT token validity (i provided you code from Spring Boot where the JWT token is checked), check against the DB for the current token, if its there, return 401.

Comment: If you made a signing key that was per-user, seems like this would be fairly easy.  Just update the key on logout.